# Zos DB2 : Commit for every 200000 recs deletion

Tags: db2, zos, jcl

I have  SQL query that deletes the recs based on where condition that filters the rec older than 20days but DBA raised an issue that it was done without commit for certain limit.

The table holds records around 7~8 Million and JCL-job-IKJ deletes the record on every week around 1~3Million.

Now, I need to find out SQL query that can perform commit on every 200000 recs deleted from the table and continues until last match rec.

Please advise on solution and suggestion any.

The job is using IKJ db2 utility to delete the recs from the table.

Comment: Use `DELETE FROM MYTAB WHERE ... FETCH FIRST 200000 ROWS ONLY` as shown in the [Example 7](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-delete), if you are  at least at v12. You may call this statement followed by COMMIT in a loop until you get SQLSTATE '02000' immediately after delete  (no rows were deleted) in a stored procedure.

Comment: I'm running sql using IKJEFT01, not wish to use stored procedure. is this can be done in SQL query itself? We will get know no of recs to  be deleted only runtime.

Comment: The same logic can be implemented in whatever program, of course.

Comment: can you share the code? since it has to run in zos batch environment where i think loop is not possible(I may wrong)

Comment: I have no idea how to run it with this IKJEFT01. If this tool allows you to run only one statement at time without procedural logic, then you must run the same job manually until the last run notifies you, that no rows were deleted. You are not able to achieve the result desired with a single SQL query.

Comment: For mass deletions you could also use the REORG-utility with DISCARD. This will be much easier on logging than mass-DELETEs and with SHLEVEL CHANGE you'll also get much better concurrency. I'm sure your DBA will assist you in setting this up.

Comment: I would recommend against changing the transaction demarcation. If the app needs to commit 2 million changes at once, then it needs to commit 2 million changes at once. I have worked with 8 million deletions in Oracle with no issues (4-hour long transaction). If you commit/rollback half way, what side effects will business have?